# How can I pass a argument to a makefile dependency?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I have the following Makefile where the `all` make target depends on a separate `setup` make target that also takes an argument. However when I `make all` the `setup` target is not invoked with the argument

```
setup:
    ...command
clean:
    ...command
all: setup myarg=value clean myarg=value
    @echo "setup & clean"
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the idea you could "pass arguments" to prerequisites.  Make is not a procedural language: prerequisites aren't "function calls".  What you've done here is declare a target `all` that depends on the targets `setup`, `myarg=value`, and `clean` (listing the same prerequisite multiple times is a no-op).

Comment: what I'm looking to do is replicate calling the make target from the shell, `make setup myarg=val`, from within another make target. Is there another way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking is if a prerequisite can inherit a target-specific variable.   In which case, yes it can -- Note, in your example you tried to intersperse the target specific variables and the prerequisites, which you can't do.   But beware -- this has sharp sticks attached.   Consider the following makefile:

```
all:

setup:
        @echo "building $@: myarg=$(myarg)"

all: myarg:=value

all: setup
        @echo "building $@: myarg=$(myarg)"

blah: setup
        @echo "building $@: myarg=$(myarg)"
```

If I do `make all`, I get:

```
tmp> make all
building setup: myarg=value
building all: myarg=value
```

Which is what you want.   But if I do `make blah`, then `setup` is run as a prerequisite of `blah`, and does not have the value set as you might expect.  It will *not* be rebuilt for `main`, even though the variable is different:

```
tmp> make blah all
building setup: myarg=
building blah: myarg=
building all: myarg=value
```

See [the make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

The command line of the `make` program is not free-form.  You can't just pass it a bunch of stuff and have that "stuff" passed through make to appear somehow inside your recipes.  `make` can only take arguments that it's defined to take: all arguments (not options) are either targets or variable assignments.  See the documentation or the man page.

It is not possible *in general* to pass arbitrary values on the make command line.  However, as I said, make does allow variables to be set on its command line.

If you run `make setup myarg=value` then this will set the `make` variable `myarg` to have the value `value`, and ask make to build the `setup` target.

So, if you write your makefile:

```
setup:
    ...command $(myarg)
```

referencing the `make` variable `myarg`, then it will "work" (I guess, you haven't made clear exactly what you want to run using `myarg`).